# books.xml transform to CSV: repeat title on each row

Tags: xml, xslt

I just received a [helpful answer to a question about xml->tabular transformation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67862133/3860847), but I don't understand how to apply it to a document where an element may have several child nodes with the same tag.

As a minimal example, consider the `books.xml` file at the [W3Schools web site](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xquery_example.asp).

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<bookstore>
    <book category="COOKING">
        <title lang="en">Everyday Italian</title>
        <author>Giada De Laurentiis</author>
    </book>
    <book category="CHILDREN">
        <title lang="en">Harry Potter</title>
        <author>J K. Rowling</author>
    </book>
    <book category="WEB">
        <title lang="en">XQuery Kick Start</title>
        <author>James McGovern</author>
        <author>Per Bothner</author>
        <author>Kurt Cagle</author>
        <author>James Linn</author>
        <author>Vaidyanathan Nagarajan</author>
    </book>
    <book category="WEB">
        <title lang="en">Learning XML</title>
        <author>Erik T. Ray</author>
    </book>
</bookstore>
```

`<bookstore>` is the root, with several `<book>` child elements. Those appear to have a single title element, but possibly multiple `<author>` elements. I would like to create a CSV or TSV document where each author appear an it's own row, with the title repeating as necessary.

The following transformation comes close :-|

```xml
<?xml version='1.0' encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet
    xmlns:xsl='http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform' version='1.0'>
    <xsl:output method="text"  encoding="UTF-8"/>
    <xsl:template match="book">
        <xsl:value-of select="title"/>
        <xsl:text></xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="author"/>
        <xsl:text></xsl:text>
        <xsl:text></xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

```
+-------------------+---------------------+
| Title             | author              |
+===================+=====================+
| Everyday Italian  | Giada De Laurentiis |
+-------------------+---------------------+
| Harry Potter      | J K. Rowling        |
+-------------------+---------------------+
| XQuery Kick Start | James McGovern      |
+-------------------+---------------------+
| Learning XML      | Erik T. Ray         |
+-------------------+---------------------+
```

But I really want the ability to generate something like this:

```
+-------------------+------------------------+
| Title             | author                 |
+===================+========================+
| Everyday Italian  | Giada De Laurentiis    |
+-------------------+------------------------+
| Harry Potter      | J K. Rowling           |
+-------------------+------------------------+
| XQuery Kick Start | James McGovern         |
+-------------------+------------------------+
| XQuery Kick Start | Per Bothner            |
+-------------------+------------------------+
| XQuery Kick Start | Kurt Cagle             |
+-------------------+------------------------+
| XQuery Kick Start | James Linn             |
+-------------------+------------------------+
| XQuery Kick Start | Vaidyanathan Nagarajan |
+-------------------+------------------------+
| Learning XML      | Erik T. Ray            |
+-------------------+------------------------+
```

Comment: Thanks @michael.hor257k. Your answer does work. Would you be offended if I waited another few hours before "accepting" your answer?

Comment: Not at all. Accepting an answer is meant to save other users the trouble of replying.

Comment: I have a lot of questions about my desired discovery and transformation of  ftp://ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov//biosample/biosample_set.xml.gz. I've been splitting them up and using the books.xml as a simpler illustration, but maybe that was a bad idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a row for each author, then create a row for each author:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8"/>

<xsl:template match="/bookstore">
    <xsl:text>Title,Author&#10;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:for-each select="book/author">
        <xsl:value-of select="../title"/>
        <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Or slightly more efficiently:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8"/>

<xsl:template match="/bookstore">
    <xsl:text>Title,Author&#10;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:for-each select="book">
        <xsl:variable name="title" select="title"/>
        <xsl:for-each select="author">
            <xsl:value-of select="$title"/>
            <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```