# Count number of elements with same tag

Tags: xml, xslt, xquery

Building upon [books.xml transform to CSV: repeat title on each row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67865180/books-xml-transform-to-csv-repeat-title-on-each-row):

For the document below, how can I count

- the number of authors per book
- the number of unique authors per book?

In this case, they would both be the same:

```
+--------------------+---------------+
|                    |               |
| Title              | Author_count  |
+--------------------+---------------+
|                    |               |
| Everyday Italian   | 1             |
+--------------------+---------------+
|                    |               |
| Harry Potter       | 1             |
+--------------------+---------------+
|                    |               |
| XQuery Kick Start  | 5             |
+--------------------+---------------+
|                    |               |
| Learning XML       | 1             |
+--------------------+---------------+
```

`xslt` or `xquery` approaches ar both OK. I would prefer tabular output.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<bookstore>
    <book category="COOKING">
        <title lang="en">Everyday Italian</title>
        <author>Giada De Laurentiis</author>
    </book>
    <book category="CHILDREN">
        <title lang="en">Harry Potter</title>
        <author>J K. Rowling</author>
    </book>
    <book category="WEB">
        <title lang="en">XQuery Kick Start</title>
        <author>James McGovern</author>
        <author>Per Bothner</author>
        <author>Kurt Cagle</author>
        <author>James Linn</author>
        <author>Vaidyanathan Nagarajan</author>
    </book>
    <book category="WEB">
        <title lang="en">Learning XML</title>
        <author>Erik T. Ray</author>
    </book>
</bookstore>
```

Comment: `count(author)` in the context of a `book` element should give the right numbers. Not sure what the "unique" part of the question refers to.

Comment: If a book can list the same author more than once (unlike your chosen example), then the XSLT answer depends on which processor you are using.

Comment: Thanks guys. I'll either clarify the 'unique authors' part of the question or delete it.

Comment: In all your questions regarding XSLT, please state which version of XSLT your processor supports. If it's XSLT 1.0, also state which processor it is, so that we know which extension functions you can use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am using BaseX v.9.5.2

**XQuery**

```xquery
xquery version "3.1";

declare context item := document {
<bookstore>
    <book category="COOKING">
        <title lang="en">Everyday Italian</title>
        <author>Giada De Laurentiis</author>
    </book>
    <book category="CHILDREN">
        <title lang="en">Harry Potter</title>
        <author>J K. Rowling</author>
    </book>
    <book category="WEB">
        <title lang="en">XQuery Kick Start</title>
        <author>James McGovern</author>
        <author>Per Bothner</author>
        <author>Kurt Cagle</author>
        <author>James Linn</author>
        <author>Vaidyanathan Nagarajan</author>
    </book>
    <book category="WEB">
        <title lang="en">Learning XML</title>
        <author>Erik T. Ray</author>
    </book>
</bookstore>
};

<root>
{
  for $x in ./bookstore/book
  return <r>
    <title>{data($x/title)}</title>
    <author_count>{count($x/author)}</author_count>
  </r>
}
</root>
```

**Output**

```xml
<root>
  <r>
    <title>Everyday Italian</title>
    <author_count>1</author_count>
  </r>
  <r>
    <title>Harry Potter</title>
    <author_count>1</author_count>
  </r>
  <r>
    <title>XQuery Kick Start</title>
    <author_count>5</author_count>
  </r>
  <r>
    <title>Learning XML</title>
    <author_count>1</author_count>
  </r>
</root>
```