# XQuery 3: Count occurrences of element names across document

Tags: xml, grouping, xquery, counting, basex

Building on [Count number of elements with same tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67874519/count-number-of-elements-with-same-tag)

I will be running this query with BaseX 9.5.2.

Given the data

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<bookstore>
    <book category="COOKING">
        <title lang="en">Everyday Italian</title>
        <author>Giada De Laurentiis</author>
    </book>
    <book category="CHILDREN">
        <title lang="en">Harry Potter</title>
        <author>J K. Rowling</author>
    </book>
    <book category="WEB">
        <title lang="en">XQuery Kick Start</title>
        <author>James McGovern</author>
        <author>Per Bothner</author>
        <author>Kurt Cagle</author>
        <author>James Linn</author>
        <author>Vaidyanathan Nagarajan</author>
    </book>
    <book category="WEB">
        <title lang="en">Learning XML</title>
        <author>Erik T. Ray</author>
    </book>
</bookstore>
```

I would like to generate a table like this

```
+----------+--------------+
|          |              |
| Element  | total_count  |
+----------+--------------+
|          |              |
| title    | 4            |
+----------+--------------+
|          |              |
| author   | 8            |
+----------+--------------+
```

I can get a list of the unique element names with

```
let $sep := '&#09;' (: tab :)

for $elems in doc(
  'books'
)/bookstore/book/*

let $currname := name(
  $elems
)

group by $currname

return string-join(
       (
        $currname
       ),
       $sep
)
```

That is,

```
title
author
```

I think I want to use `count()`, but I'm not sure how to say that I want to count the parent books. In my answered question mentioned above, the element name to count was hard-coded in the query. In this case, I'm using a wildcard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to the grouping you already have, `count($elems)` will have the right value in the `return` clause.

I think you original use of the `let $sep` is causing problems, the grouping `count($elems)` I suggested works fine for me at https://xqueryfiddle.liberty-development.net/bFDbxm7 where I have moved the `$sep` to a declared variable.

Comment: I updated the return block to `return string-join(($currname, count($elems) ), $sep)` 
but got 'Item expected, sequence found...'

Comment: It might be due to the wrong binding of the `$sep`, I don't think it is the addition of `count($elems)` that cause this.

Comment: It appears to me that your original example should already give you  the error about item expected but sequence found as the `let $sep` is also affecting by the grouping and binds more than one string to that variable. So declare it separately or use `$seq[1]` in the `return` clause.

Comment: I'm sure you're onto something important that I need to learn, but I can assure you that my data and query above return the output I just added.

Comment: Not for me with Saxon https://xqueryfiddle.liberty-development.net/bFDbxm7/1, will check later with BaseX.

Comment: BaseX rewrites your original attempt to e.g. `distinct-values(document { ... }/bookstore/book/* ! name(.))` so that way you don't get the error about `$sep` being bound to a sequence of more than one item.

Comment: If you want to have the `let $sep` then in the `return` clause after the grouping use e.g. `$sep[1]` or `head($sep)`.

Comment: Great. I have a working query now and will post it as soon as I am eligible to submit a self answer. I do like having my definitions of column and line separators at the top of the query. I guess I should just get more comfortable with accepting an xml response :-) Then I wouldn't need to define sparators, right?

Comment: The binding change of the variable in the `let` clause preceding the `for` clause is caused by the `group by` clause, it doesn't have anything to do with the serialization or output format.

Answer (score 0):

I am using BaseX v.9.5.2

Please try the following XQuery.

**XQuery**

```
xquery version "3.1";

declare context item := document {
<bookstore>
    <book category="COOKING">
        <title lang="en">Everyday Italian</title>
        <author>Giada De Laurentiis</author>
    </book>
    <book category="CHILDREN">
        <title lang="en">Harry Potter</title>
        <author>J K. Rowling</author>
    </book>
    <book category="WEB">
        <title lang="en">XQuery Kick Start</title>
        <author>James McGovern</author>
        <author>Per Bothner</author>
        <author>Kurt Cagle</author>
        <author>James Linn</author>
        <author>Vaidyanathan Nagarajan</author>
    </book>
    <book category="WEB">
        <title lang="en">Learning XML</title>
        <author>Erik T. Ray</author>
    </book>
</bookstore>
};

<root>
{
  let $title := count(./bookstore/book/title)
  let $author := count(distinct-values(./bookstore/book/author))
  return <r>
    <title>{$title}</title>
    <unique_author_count>{$author}</unique_author_count>
  </r>
}
</root>
```

**XQuery #2**

```
declare namespace output = "http://www.w3.org/2010/xslt-xquery-serialization";

declare option output:method 'text';
declare option output:item-separator '&#10;';
    
declare context item := document {
<bookstore>
    <book category="COOKING">
        <title lang="en">Everyday Italian</title>
        <author>Giada De Laurentiis</author>
    </book>
    <book category="CHILDREN">
        <title lang="en">Harry Potter</title>
        <author>J K. Rowling</author>
    </book>
    <book category="WEB">
        <title lang="en">XQuery Kick Start</title>
        <author>James McGovern</author>
        <author>Per Bothner</author>
        <author>Kurt Cagle</author>
        <author>James Linn</author>
        <author>Vaidyanathan Nagarajan</author>
    </book>
    <book category="WEB">
        <title lang="en">Learning XML</title>
        <author>Erik T. Ray</author>
    </book>
</bookstore>
};

let $sep := '&#09;' (: tab :)

for $elems in ./bookstore/book/*
let $currname := local-name($elems)
group by $currname
return string-join(($currname, count(distinct-values($elems[local-name()=$currname])),$sep))
```

Comment: THanks for your response, but I want a generalizable query that discovers the different kinds of elements that appear as children of a root like `/bookstore/book` and counts the occurrences of each. That would include title and author elements for this input. You Have hard-coded the element types into your solution.

Comment: @MarkMiller, you need to be very specific what you are after. It should be **a minimal reproducible example**. For your case it means the following: (1) Input XML.
(2) Your logic, and XQuery that tries to implement it.
(3) Desired output based on the #1 above.
(4) XQuery processor and its version.

Comment: I really appreciate your contribution, but all of those parts of the minimal reproducible querion are present. @Martin Honen and I are working it out in xquery fiddle now.

Comment: @MarkMiller, #1 ne #3

Comment: Thanks,this is helpful. The counting is correct now, but the concatenation isn't what I was expecting. "title4", followed by four tabs, appears on the first line and "author8", followed by eight tabs, appears on the second. I'm going to keep experimenting.